# How can I get the right location for a javascript file?

Tags: c#, javascript, href, src

I want to load jquery script in the header of my cshtml file like this:

```
<script src="@Href("~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.6.min.js") type="text/javascript">
```

However, this code gives me `http://localhost:1304/Scripts/js/jquery-1.6.min.js%20type=?_=1325728429624` , where it doesn't find the file. The cshtml file is in `D:\svn\Web\Healthcare\trunk\test.Web.Healthcare\Areas\Framework\Administration\Entity` and the jquery is in `D:\svn\Web\Framework\Trunk\test.Web.Framework\Scripts\js`. How can I set the src right so that it finds the jquery file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know the answer in C# sorry, but you do seem to be missing a closing quote at the end of your src attribute - might be contributing to your issues?

Comment: I don't think merely contributing...causing is probably more accurate :P Close off that quote and it should sort the problem - notice the filename goes on to "%20type=" at the end, exactly what comes after the missing quote.
So yeah, try `<script src="@Href("~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.6.min.js")" type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.6.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: that still gives me GET http://localhost:1304/Scripts/js/jquery-1.6.min.js?_=1325729441302 404 (Not Found) error

Comment: Even if for some reason some parameter is attached you should be able to open this script if it exists. Copy this link into address line in you browser, delete everything after "js" and see if it exists. If not the problem is in this file - it doesn't exist really.

Comment: Also, please specify which project is it - asp.net or asp.net mvc, it may be important.

Comment: Oh, I can see - it's asp.net mvc. So, the problem maybe in the routing. But firstly I would like to ask you to make sure that file exists.

Comment: I'm sure that the file exists, I copied the address from the properties

Comment: Which properties? If you enter this address into the browser address line does it find it? If no, I suppose there are additional folders - real or virtual ones - that spoil the picture. From other comments I could see the full path to the file, includes Framework/Trunk. What is this? And can you see this file in your solution tree?

Comment: The full file path is D:\svn\Web\Framework\Trunk\test.Web.Framework\Scripts\jquery-1.6.min.js

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter which path is on the disk. It may be any. The more important which path is when you run your app. Especially starting from the root folder. Can you please look at your solution tree in the VS and try to find this file?

Comment: Try to do the following thing: copy the js file from its location into your app Script/js/ folder. I bet you will be able to access it. Now I can see the problem - you use the path from the server's root to the file that is not in the app at all. The another solution is - to figure out which app is this js file in and then include it (app) into your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use

```
<script src="/Framework/Trunk/test.Web.Framework/Scripts/js/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: This still gives me a http://localhost:1304/Scripts/js/jquery-1.6.min.js?_=1325729614345 404 (Not Found) error

Comment: Assuming the root of the web is d:\svn\web, you have to go all the way back to the root (the leading /) then back up to the scripts directory. I have updated the answer with this path.

Comment: I don't know how I can see if it is the root, but I get GET http://localhost:1304/Framework/Trunk/test.Web.Framework/Scripts/js/jquery-1.6.min.js?_=1325730372044 404 (Not Found) now

Comment: You will probably need to go into IIS Manager to see what the root directory is. If the root is further up (D:\svn\Web\Healthcare\trunk\test.Web.Healthcare, for example) then you will not be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Does the two files not in a application.

1: D:\svn\Web\Healthcare\trunk\test.Web.Healthcare\Areas\Framework\Administration\Entity

2: D:\svn\Web\Framework\Trunk\test.Web.Framework\Scripts\js

So you can not visit the jquery js, unless you use the absolute url.